# Extracting named entities to columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a Spacy NER model, where I am trying to extract each entity identified in a dataframe column as a separate column - so for example to create and populate the 'GPE' and 'PERSON columns:

| Text | GPE | PERSON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| random text London George | London | George |

However, i'm not sure how to do this and match the corresponding entities / label lists. I've trialled a few ways with no success such as:

```
def person(v):
        if 'PERSON' in [ent.label_ for ent in ner_model(v).ents]:
            return [ent.text for ent in ner_model(v).ents]


df['Person'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda v: person(v))

df.head()
```

This just returns a list of entities and I have been unable to get code containing '=='Person'' to work... I wondered if anyone else has solved this issue otherwise appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you seem to assume that there's one entity per label per sentence, which is absolutely not guaranteed to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

I think i've got a solution by extracting all entities to a column:

```
def all_ents(v):
        return [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in ner_model(v).ents]

df['Entities'] = df['Combined'].apply(lambda v: all_ents(v))

df.head()
```

Then going over this column with the following, eg:

```
def person(v):
    r = [(x,y) for x,y in v if ('PERSON' == y)]
    return [(x) for x,y in r]

df['Person'] = df['Entities'].apply(lambda v: person(v))

df.head()
```

Seems to be working!